# Module not found in angular 2

Tags: angular

I'm newbie to angular 2. I had created a custom component and even did registered in app.module.ts
Find my folder structure :

[image]

emp.component.ts :

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core'

@Component({
selector:'emp-tag',
templateUrl:'./Employee/emp.component.html'
})
export class EmployeeComponent
{
    title : 'This is Employee Component';
}
```

emp.component.html :

```
Hai {{title}}
```

Registered in app.module.ts file as like below :

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import {EmployeeComponent} from './Employee/emp.component'

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    EmployeeComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

When I run my application by using ng server --open, I'm facing a compile time error as like module is not found in command prompt window as like below image

[image]

From my folder structure, I had given correct path in app.module.ts file.

Comment: Did you read the error message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change the path as follows, because you are in the same folder

**`templateUrl:'./emp.component.html`**

**Complete code**

```
@Component({
selector:'emp-tag',
templateUrl:'./emp.component.html'
})
export class EmployeeComponent
{
    title : 'This is Employee Component';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**emp.component.ts**

Use

```
templateUrl:'./emp.component.html'
```

Instead of

```
templateUrl:'./Employee/emp.component.html'
```

Comment: @Sajeetharan, one question is going to have only one valid answer. Though, it can be provided in a different ways.